# Help writing a clever analogy for an essay

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm a final year high school student trying to write a university essay on the importance of insight (deep understanding) or intuition in physics as opposed to math which relies on rigorous formulation.

Can anyone think of a clever statement expressing the importance of 1) a deep understanding (insight) and 2) mathematical formulation or rigour, those two requirements being expressed in the light of a clue  that both are necessary for physics to work and that physics cannot exist without both.

I was thinking that maybe an analogy like “intuition and math are to physics as...”.

**Edit:**
A more precise context, as requested:

> “Rigorous reasoning is crucial in mathematics, and insight plays an important secondary role these days. In the natural sciences, I would say that the order of these two virtues is reversed. Rigor is, of course, very important. But the most important value is insight—insight into the workings of the world. It may be because there is another guarantor of correctness in the sciences, namely, the empirical evidence from observation and experiments.”

I want a statement expressing the necessity and importance of **both** insight and mathematical formulation; the basic idea of my paragraph is that physics cannot work without one of them, and how I learned that as I matured academically

Comment: Your question is not intelligible. Give a more precise context so that people can clearly understand what you are asking.

Comment: There is a logical disconnect in your question. You talk about both insight and maths being needed for physics, and yet you omit mathematics in your final sentence and substitute physics.. Do you instead mean, "When doing physics,  insight is to mathematics as A is to B"?  Please clarify.  NOTE: Edit to question made after I wrote this.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out. I have made a correction

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH ELU is not a good site to get composition advice.

Comment: Im sorry. I’m new. Could you suggest a better alternative?

Comment: Regrettably, it is not the purpose of this site to provide opinion-based contributions to other's work.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a biological analogy: if intuition and maths are the flesh and bones of physics, then maths is certainly the bones: it provides strength, structure and substance.  Intuition, then, plays the part of the flesh, it gives form, function, and - importantly - movement: progress.  Without intuition, physics would be as static as a museum skeleton.

Comment: Clever idea. Didn’t think of that

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking that maybe an analogy like “intuition and math are to
> physics as...”.

The problem is that intuition is an essential factor in most research so it is difficult not to repeat it.

My best shot (although we are not supposed to be authors on this site) is

“Intuition and math are to physics as experience and ingredients are to cookery."

Answer (score -1):

Amusing…

- Intuition is to physics what mother's milk is to the offspring but mathematics are to physics what teeth are to the offspring.